# #include inside #if - #endif

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If I put a `#include` inside a `#if` - `#endif` will the preprocessor check the `#if` to see if the content of the `#include` will be included?

```
#if 0

#include <foo>

#endif
```

In this case, will `foo` always be included or not?

Comment: I will not be included by the preprocessor.

Comment: Isn't this trivial to test?

Comment: @user2079303 I don't recommend "just trying it" when you're not sure about something in a language with undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BoBTFish You should always try it first. If he did, he wouldn't need to ask "In this case, will foo always be included" because he'd know that's not true. If he did and actually found a case where that happens, it would be very important detail to mention in the question. You can't test all the cases though, so "In my test, foo was not included but are there exceptions to this?" is still a valid question.

Comment: I'm on the phone and I just want to ask a quick clear question and get a quick answer. But apparently that's not acceptable to some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the condition is false, then everything between `#if` and `#endif` will be omitted. That includes any `#include` directives, so the file won't be included.

Answer (score 2):

The outer condition is evaluated first. If it returns a false type value then the content within will not be processed.